# Restoring/Accessing Synology Raid 1

Tags: mount, raid, data-recovery, nas, mdadm

I was recently asked to try to restore the data from a raid on a synology NAS. The raid consists of 2 disks of 2TB in size. It is a raid 1.

From what I was told, One of the drives has failed and the backup drive is still intact. I know which one of the two is which.

Reassembling the raid has not produced any results. For some reason, the raid is always recognized as md127 after every single mdadm command I execute, no matter what md I declare in the --assemble command. When I declare one of the drives as missing, mdadm starts to look for a drive called missing instead of declaring the array as degraded.
At the end of the assembly command, the final result is always "No suitable drives found fo dev/md/e_nas:2.

```
sudo mdadm --stop /dev/md127
sudo mdadm --assemble --verbose /dev/md0 /dev/sdb3 /dev/sda3
mdadm: looking for devices for /dev/md0
mdadm: /dev/sda3 is busy - skipping
mdadm: Merging with already-assembled /dev/md/e_nas:2
mdadm: /dev/sda3 is identified as a member of /dev/md/e_nas:2, slot 32769.
mdadm: /dev/sdb3 is identified as a member of /dev/md/e_nas:2, slot 32768.
mdadm: No suitable drives found for /dev/md/e_nas:2

sudo mdadm --detail --scan
INACTIVE-ARRAY /dev/md127 metadata=1.2 name=e_nas:2 UUID=213397ad:6d3ef545:dae75da0:662ff5a8

sudo mdadm --stop /dev/md127
sudo mdadm -Afvs
mdadm: looking for devices for further assembly
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/sdc1
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sdc
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/nvme0n1p8
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/nvme0n1p7
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/nvme0n1p6
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/nvme0n1p5
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/nvme0n1p4
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/nvme0n1p3
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/nvme0n1p2
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/nvme0n1p1
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/nvme0n1
mdadm: No super block found on /dev/sdb2 (Expected magic a92b4efc, got 32323533)
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdb2
mdadm: No super block found on /dev/sdb1 (Expected magic a92b4efc, got 00000099)
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdb1
mdadm: No super block found on /dev/sdb (Expected magic a92b4efc, got 00000000)
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdb
mdadm: No super block found on /dev/sda2 (Expected magic a92b4efc, got 6d783f3c)
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sda2
mdadm: No super block found on /dev/sda1 (Expected magic a92b4efc, got 00000099)
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sda1
mdadm: No super block found on /dev/sda (Expected magic a92b4efc, got 00000000)
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sda
mdadm: /dev/sdb3 is identified as a member of /dev/md/e_nas:2, slot 32768.
mdadm: /dev/sda3 is identified as a member of /dev/md/e_nas:2, slot 32769.
mdadm: No suitable drives found for /dev/md/e_nas:2
mdadm: looking for devices for further assembly
mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically
```

Here is some of the data on the drives using the --examine command.

```
/dev/sda3:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 213397ad:6d3ef545:dae75da0:662ff5a8
           Name : e_nas:2
  Creation Time : Fri Oct  9 23:42:52 2015
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 3897385120 sectors (1858.42 GiB 1995.46 GB)
     Array Size : 1948692416 KiB (1858.42 GiB 1995.46 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3897384832 sectors (1858.42 GiB 1995.46 GB)
    Data Offset : 2048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=1968 sectors, after=288 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : c396622f:050e9557:36e44171:82178cbd

    Update Time : Sun Jan 29 21:35:43 2023
       Checksum : a8f09696 - correct
         Events : 5185


   Device Role : Active device 32769
   Array State : .. ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
WARNING Array state is inconsistent - each number should appear only once
 0:- 1:32769 2:- 3:- 4:- 5:- 6:- 7:- 8:- 9:- 10:- 11:- 12:- 13:- 14:- 15:- 16:- 17:- 18:- 19:- 20:- 21:- 22:- 23:- 24:- 25:- 26:- 27:- 28:- 29:- 30:- 31:- 32:- 33:- 34:- 35:- 36:- 37:- 38:- 39:- 40:- 41:- 42:- 43:- 44:- 45:- 46:- 47:- 48:- 49:- 50:- 51:- 52:- 53:- 54:- 55:- 56:- 57:- 58:- 59:- 60:- 61:- 62:- 63:- 64:- 65:- 66:- 67:- 68:- 69:- 70:- 71:- 72:- 73:- 74:- 75:- 76:- 77:- 78:- 79:- 80:- 81:- 82:- 83:- 84:- 85:- 86:- 87:- 88:- 89:- 90:- 91:- 92:- 93:- 94:- 95:- 96:- 97:- 98:- 99:- 100:- 101:- 102:- 103:- 104:- 105:- 106:- 107:- 108:- 109:- 110:- 111:- 112:- 113:- 114:- 115:- 116:- 117:- 118:- 119:- 120:- 121:- 122:- 123:- 124:- 125:- 126:- 127:- 128:- 129:- 130:- 131:- 132:- 133:- 134:- 135:- 136:- 137:- 138:- 139:- 140:- 141:- 142:- 143:- 144:- 145:- 146:- 147:- 148:- 149:- 150:- 151:- 152:- 153:- 154:- 155:- 156:- 157:- 158:- 159:- 160:- 161:- 162:- 163:- 164:- 165:- 166:- 167:- 168:- 169:- 170:- 171:- 172:- 173:- 174:- 175:- 176:- 177:- 178:- 179:- 180:- 181:- 182:- 183:- 184:- 185:- 186:- 187:- 188:- 189:- 190:- 191:- 192:- 193:- 194:- 195:- 196:- 197:- 198:- 199:- 200:- 201:- 202:- 203:- 204:- 205:- 206:- 207:- 208:- 209:- 210:- 211:- 212:- 213:- 214:- 215:- 216:- 217:- 218:- 219:- 220:- 221:- 222:- 223:- 224:- 225:- 226:- 227:- 228:- 229:- 230:- 231:- 232:- 233:- 234:- 235:- 236:- 237:- 238:- 239:- 240:- 241:- 242:- 243:- 244:- 245:- 246:- 247:- 248:- 249:- 250:- 251:- 252:- 253:- 254:- 255:- 256:- 257:- 258:- 259:- 260:- 261:- 262:- 263:- 264:- 265:- 266:- 267:- 268:- 269:- 270:- 271:- 272:- 273:- 274:- 275:- 276:- 277:- 278:- 279:- 280:- 281:- 282:- 283:- 284:- 285:- 286:- 287:- 288:- 289:- 290:- 291:- 292:- 293:- 294:- 295:- 296:- 297:- 298:- 299:- 300:- 301:- 302:- 303:- 304:- 305:- 306:- 307:- 308:- 309:- 310:- 311:- 312:- 313:- 314:- 315:- 316:- 317:- 318:- 319:- 320:- 321:- 322:- 323:- 324:- 325:- 326:- 327:- 328:- 329:- 330:- 331:- 332:- 333:- 334:- 335:- 336:- 337:- 338:- 339:- 340:- 341:- 342:- 343:- 344:- 345:- 346:- 347:- 348:- 349:- 350:- 351:- 352:- 353:- 354:- 355:- 356:- 357:- 358:- 359:- 360:- 361:- 362:- 363:- 364:- 365:- 366:- 367:- 368:- 369:- 370:- 371:- 372:- 373:- 374:- 375:- 376:- 377:- 378:- 379:- 380:- 381:- 382:- 383:-



/dev/sdb3:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 213397ad:6d3ef545:dae75da0:662ff5a8
           Name : e_nas:2
  Creation Time : Fri Oct  9 23:42:52 2015
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 3897385120 sectors (1858.42 GiB 1995.46 GB)
     Array Size : 1948692416 KiB (1858.42 GiB 1995.46 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3897384832 sectors (1858.42 GiB 1995.46 GB)
    Data Offset : 2048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=1968 sectors, after=288 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 44e9ebd4:7a7aaf74:5bb8bfbd:98d0343f

    Update Time : Fri Jan 20 19:32:43 2023
       Checksum : b9ab54fe - correct
         Events : 242


   Device Role : Active device 32768
   Array State : .. ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
WARNING Array state is inconsistent - each number should appear only once
 0:32768 1:- 2:- 3:- 4:- 5:- 6:- 7:- 8:- 9:- 10:- 11:- 12:- 13:- 14:- 15:- 16:- 17:- 18:- 19:- 20:- 21:- 22:- 23:- 24:- 25:- 26:- 27:- 28:- 29:- 30:- 31:- 32:- 33:- 34:- 35:- 36:- 37:- 38:- 39:- 40:- 41:- 42:- 43:- 44:- 45:- 46:- 47:- 48:- 49:- 50:- 51:- 52:- 53:- 54:- 55:- 56:- 57:- 58:- 59:- 60:- 61:- 62:- 63:- 64:- 65:- 66:- 67:- 68:- 69:- 70:- 71:- 72:- 73:- 74:- 75:- 76:- 77:- 78:- 79:- 80:- 81:- 82:- 83:- 84:- 85:- 86:- 87:- 88:- 89:- 90:- 91:- 92:- 93:- 94:- 95:- 96:- 97:- 98:- 99:- 100:- 101:- 102:- 103:- 104:- 105:- 106:- 107:- 108:- 109:- 110:- 111:- 112:- 113:- 114:- 115:- 116:- 117:- 118:- 119:- 120:- 121:- 122:- 123:- 124:- 125:- 126:- 127:- 128:- 129:- 130:- 131:- 132:- 133:- 134:- 135:- 136:- 137:- 138:- 139:- 140:- 141:- 142:- 143:- 144:- 145:- 146:- 147:- 148:- 149:- 150:- 151:- 152:- 153:- 154:- 155:- 156:- 157:- 158:- 159:- 160:- 161:- 162:- 163:- 164:- 165:- 166:- 167:- 168:- 169:- 170:- 171:- 172:- 173:- 174:- 175:- 176:- 177:- 178:- 179:- 180:- 181:- 182:- 183:- 184:- 185:- 186:- 187:- 188:- 189:- 190:- 191:- 192:- 193:- 194:- 195:- 196:- 197:- 198:- 199:- 200:- 201:- 202:- 203:- 204:- 205:- 206:- 207:- 208:- 209:- 210:- 211:- 212:- 213:- 214:- 215:- 216:- 217:- 218:- 219:- 220:- 221:- 222:- 223:- 224:- 225:- 226:- 227:- 228:- 229:- 230:- 231:- 232:- 233:- 234:- 235:- 236:- 237:- 238:- 239:- 240:- 241:- 242:- 243:- 244:- 245:- 246:- 247:- 248:- 249:- 250:- 251:- 252:- 253:- 254:- 255:- 256:- 257:- 258:- 259:- 260:- 261:- 262:- 263:- 264:- 265:- 266:- 267:- 268:- 269:- 270:- 271:- 272:- 273:- 274:- 275:- 276:- 277:- 278:- 279:- 280:- 281:- 282:- 283:- 284:- 285:- 286:- 287:- 288:- 289:- 290:- 291:- 292:- 293:- 294:- 295:- 296:- 297:- 298:- 299:- 300:- 301:- 302:- 303:- 304:- 305:- 306:- 307:- 308:- 309:- 310:- 311:- 312:- 313:- 314:- 315:- 316:- 317:- 318:- 319:- 320:- 321:- 322:- 323:- 324:- 325:- 326:- 327:- 328:- 329:- 330:- 331:- 332:- 333:- 334:- 335:- 336:- 337:- 338:- 339:- 340:- 341:- 342:- 343:- 344:- 345:- 346:- 347:- 348:- 349:- 350:- 351:- 352:- 353:- 354:- 355:- 356:- 357:- 358:- 359:- 360:- 361:- 362:- 363:- 364:- 365:- 366:- 367:- 368:- 369:- 370:- 371:- 372:- 373:- 374:- 375:- 376:- 377:- 378:- 379:- 380:- 381:- 382:- 383:-
```

Here are the details of the md127.

```
/dev/md127:
           Version : 1.2
        Raid Level : raid1
     Total Devices : 2
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

             State : inactive
   Working Devices : 2

              Name : e_nas:2
              UUID : 213397ad:6d3ef545:dae75da0:662ff5a8
            Events : 242

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice

       -       8       19        -        /dev/sdb3
       -       8        3        -        /dev/sda3
```

Here are the two disks in fdisk -l.

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1.82 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD20EFRX-68E
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00085d7c

Device     Boot   Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1          2048    4982527    4980480  2.4G fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda2       4982528    9176831    4194304    2G fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda3       9437184 3906824351 3897387168  1.8T fd Linux raid autodetect


Disk /dev/sdb: 1.82 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD20EFRX-68E
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000c2a5c

Device     Boot   Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1          2048    4982527    4980480  2.4G fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb2       4982528    9176831    4194304    2G fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb3       9437184 3906824351 3897387168  1.8T fd Linux raid autodetect
```

If any more information is needed, I will be happy to provide it. I am not exactly well versed when it comes to raids and data recovery so any help or advise will be very appreciated.

**Edit1:**

Here is the some more data that is needed as pointer out in [Nikita Kipriyanovs comment](https://superuser.com/users/528652/nikita-kipriyanov)

Result of the lsblk:

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda           8:0    0  1.8T  0 disk 
├─sda1        8:1    0  2.4G  0 part 
├─sda2        8:2    0    2G  0 part 
└─sda3        8:3    0  1.8T  0 part 
  └─md127     9:127  0    0B  0 md   
sdb           8:16   0  1.8T  0 disk 
├─sdb1        8:17   0  2.4G  0 part 
├─sdb2        8:18   0    2G  0 part 
└─sdb3        8:19   0  1.8T  0 part 
  └─md127     9:127  0    0B  0 md
```

Result of the blkid:

```
/dev/sdb2: UUID="acfd5239-cd13-40e7-bef6-6bc3124f080c" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="000c2a5c-02"
/dev/sdb3: UUID="213397ad-6d3e-f545-dae7-5da0662ff5a8" UUID_SUB="44e9ebd4-7a7a-af74-5bb8-bfbd98d0343f" LABEL="e_nas:2" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="000c2a5c-03"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="14da5054-869b-884b-3017-a5a8c86610be" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="000c2a5c-01"
/dev/sdc1: PARTUUID="01bbceed-01"
/dev/sda2: UUID="26036c54-8e86-bf3a-d6dd-008535d3b9f1" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="00085d7c-02"
/dev/sda3: UUID="213397ad-6d3e-f545-dae7-5da0662ff5a8" UUID_SUB="c396622f-050e-9557-36e4-417182178cbd" LABEL="e_nas:2" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="00085d7c-03"
/dev/sda1: UUID="14da5054-869b-884b-3017-a5a8c86610be" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="00085d7c-01"
```

Here are some other things I realized while continuing to try and solve this.
When trying to mount the md I get this error:

```
mount: /mnt/md127: can't read superblock on /dev/md127.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.
```

The dmesg entry states:

```
FAT-fs (md127): unable to read boot sector
```

As also pointed out by [Nikita Kipriyanov](https://superuser.com/users/528652/nikita-kipriyanov), I ran vgchange -ay. This seemed to change something, as the details of the raid have changed. The 2 volumes have been changed to removed and a third one has been added as a spare. Here is the new output:

```
/dev/md127:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Fri Oct  9 23:42:52 2015
        Raid Level : raid1
     Used Dev Size : 1948692416 (1858.42 GiB 1995.46 GB)
      Raid Devices : 2
     Total Devices : 1
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

       Update Time : Sun Jan 29 21:35:43 2023
             State : active, FAILED, Not Started 
    Active Devices : 0
   Working Devices : 1
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 1

Consistency Policy : unknown

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       -       0        0        0      removed
       -       0        0        1      removed

       -       8        3        -      spare   /dev/sda3
```

Comment: It is absolutely unimportant which device name it gets. Be it md0 or md127, it doesn't change anything. Just accept whatever it does and continue. But to help you to go further we need to see your `lsblk` and, possibly, `blkid`. I suspect there'll be LVM on top of the RAID, so you'll need to run `vgchange -ay` after array is assembled.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I edited the post to add the data you requested. `vgchange -ay` seems to have resulted in one of the drives being recognized as a spare. The details for that are in the new `mdadm -D /dev/md127` output I added at the end of the post.

Comment: This looks strange It assembled an array, but after an attempt to use it looks like metadata is broken. So, you say one of those drives failed? Which one?

Comment: `/dev/sda` is the one that failed.
In the NAS itself, all the data was still visible but we couldn't copy all of it to another location, that's how I know that the data is still there.

Comment: Alright I have another update. These two disks from the raid were given to me by another person saying they've tried everything and if possible, I can try some things too to try to recover the data. They told me that one disk was still good. In my last attempt to fix this problem, I've risked it all and created a new raid1 on the corrupted disk and then added the safe one as a spare so it's data is recovered onto the first one. Then mdadm told me for the first time that both of them had broken down. So I guess that disk never did contain any data anymore. This can be considered "solved" now.